# Write log-file when testing with NUnit

Tags: c#, log4net

I have a test-assembly (`MyTestProject`) where I want to write some logging using log4net. Thus I created a config-file with the same name as the assembly where I set up the logging as suggested [here](http://www.ofconsulting.com/publicportal/ofc-tech-blog/92-configure-log4net-with-nunit.html):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<!-- .NET application configuration file
 This file must have the exact same name as your application with
 .config appended to it. For example if your application is testApp.exe
 then the config file must be testApp.exe.config it must also be in the
 same directory as the application. -->
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    <!-- Register the section handler for the log4net section -->
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net" />
    <sectionGroup name="NUnit">
      <!--  For .NET 2.0 Beta 2 replace the lines with the following -->
      <section name="TestCaseBuilder" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler, System, Version=2.0.50215.44, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      <section name="TestRunner" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler, System, Version=2.0.50215.44, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <NUnit>
      <TestCaseBuilder>
        <add key="OldStyleTestCases" value="false" />
      </TestCaseBuilder>
      <TestRunner>
        <!-- Valid values are STA,MTA. Others ignored. -->
        <add key="ApartmentState" value="STA" />
        <!-- See ThreadPriority enum for other valid values -->
        <add key="ThreadPriority" value="Normal" />
      </TestRunner>
    </NUnit>
    <appSettings>
      <add key="ApartmentState" value="STA" />
      <add key="apartment" value="STA" />
    </appSettings>

    <!-- This section contains the log4net configuration settings -->
    <log4net debug="true">

      <!-- Define some output appenders -->

      <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender,log4net" >
        <param name="File" value="D:/data.log" />
        <param name="AppendToFile" value="false" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout,log4net">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c [%x] &lt;%X{auth}&gt; - %m%n" />
        </layout>
      </appender>


      <!-- Setup the root category, add the appenders and set the default priority -->
      <root>
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
      </root>
    </log4net>
</configuration>
```

Within my code I set up the logging as follows:

```
[TestFixture]
public class MyTest
{

    private readonly ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

    [TestFixtureSetUp] 
    public void Init() 
    {
        log.Info("Something to log");
        ... 
    }
}
```

However when I run my tests no such file `D:/data.log` is created. Even more suspicious when I debug the code and add a watch to the appenders from `log` I get an empty collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I post this together as it stuck me for hours.

I looked into the directory where the file should stay, there was one (apperently from an earlier test-run as its timestamp was not recent). Trying to delete the file got me a message that it is currently in use from `nunit-agent-x86.exe`. So I killed the process in TaskManager and re-run my tests. Now everything works correct and I get my logging into the file.

Answer (score -1):

This Could have been solved if you give value for key, AppendToFile as true..
As logger appends logging to the existing file and wont try to delete it.